# Using FromBase64Transform with CryptoStream?

Tags: .net

I have a .NET string which is Base64 encoded representation of an array of encrypted bytes.  It is produced like this:

```
String Encrypt( String message )
{
    CryptoStream cryptostream = ...
    StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter( cryptostream );
    ...
    return Convert.ToBase64String( ... );
}
```

Now I want a decryption function like

```
String Decrypt( String cypher )
{
    TextReader reader = new StringReader( cypher );
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ cypher.Length ];
    for( int i = 0; i < cypher.Length; ++i )
    {
        buffer[ i ] = (byte) reader.Read();
    }
    FromBase64Transform transformer = new FromBase64Transform();
    MemoryStream raw = new MemoryStream
    ( 
        transformer.TransformFinalBlock( buffer, 0, buffer.Length )
    );
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to use FromBase64Transform *directly* with CryptoStream (as the .NET documentation suggests), instead of manually converting the string to bytes, then manually decoding the bytes, and finally decrypting the decoded bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always the the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) class to convert the string into an array of Byte.

An example:

```
    public static string DeCryptString(string s) {
        byte[] b = System.Convert.FromBase64String(s);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b)) 
        using (CryptoStream cs = /* Create decrypting stream here */)
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs)) {
            string buf = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return buf;
        }
    } // DeCryptString
```

Comment: Actually, the memory stream can be initialized directly using the byte array returned by Convert in this example. This avoids calls to Write and Seek.

Comment: @Jerome, thx, I've edited the example according your tip. Reading it back, I don't even know why I did it the complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no public built-in way to stream from a string, as of .NET 3.5.

You can implement a simple StringStream class that inherits from Stream, which will free you from having to convert the string to an array of bytes.